# connect ETIMEDOUT npm grunt module

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I am not able to install grunt module.

```
C:\Users\maah4>npm install -g grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\maah4
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\maah4\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have also tried following config. But It did not work.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I have some proxy but I am able to access this via browser.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you have a firewall in your home/office that blocks npm.

You can fix it if you set the proxy via npm

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy-server-address:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy-server-address:8080
```

Maybe this links helps you: http://blog.michaelfasani.com/tag/npm/

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your proxy value in an environment variable. `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable. Run this in your command prompt.

1. `SETX HTTP_PROXY http://proxy-server-address:8080` *(It should return SUCCESS. You can also do this in System Properties...Advanced...Environment Variables)*
2. Close your command prompt window and open again. (*This ensures your new environment variable will be used in your session*.)
3. Now run your install command: `npm install -g grunt-cli`